Dynamically handling multiple CSV files with unknown schemas using Pydantic and FastAPI
I'm building a FastAPI application that needs to process and serve data from 6 different CSV files, each with its own schema. I'm using Pydantic for data validation but facing challenges due to the dynamic nature of the data. Here's my specific situation:
Each CSV file has about 40 fields with unknown data types (except for the ID field).
Some fields may be optional or empty.
The total data size is about 60MB.
The API needs to return a JSON object containing 6 key-value pairs, where each value is an array of objects corresponding to one CSV file.
Snippet of a mocked version of the data:
{
  "fruits": [
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "color": "red",
      "weight": 150
    },
    {
      "name": "banana",
      "color": "yellow",
      "weight": 120
    },
    {
      "name": "orange",
      "color": "orange",
      "weight": 140
    }
  ],
  "animals": [
    {
      "species": "lion",
      "habitat": "savanna",
      "lifespan": 15
    },
    {
      "species": "dolphin",
      "habitat": "ocean",
      "lifespan": 25
    },
    {
      "species": "eagle",
      "habitat": "mountains",
      "lifespan": 20
    }
  ],
......
  ]
}

Current approach:
I've created 6 different Pydantic BaseModels (one for each CSV file) and a ResponseModel:
class ResponseModel(BaseModel):
    fruits: Optional[List[FruitModel]]
    animals: Optional[List[AnimalModel]]
    cities: Optional[List[CityModel]]
    books: Optional[List[BookModel]]
    cars: Optional[List[CarModel]]
    planets: Optional[List[PlanetModel]]

Problem:
This approach isn't flexible enough to handle potential schema changes in the CSV files, and manually creating models for 40 fields per file is error-prone.
Questions:

How can I dynamically create Pydantic models based on the CSV file
contents at runtime?
What's an efficient way to infer field types and
handle optional fields when creating these dynamic models?
How can I modify my ResponseModel to accommodate these dynamic models?
Are there any performance considerations I should be aware of when
dealing with 60MB of data in this manner?

I'm looking for a concrete solution that allows me to handle these CSV files with unknown and potentially changing schemas while still leveraging Pydantic's validation capabilities in my FastAPI application.
I have tried looping over the rows, but this would be done every time the API is being called, I also tried storing the basemodels in memory, but it would trouble the server. Hence I am lost of whether I am utilizing pydantic correctly or not.

Don't worry about 60mb of data. It's nothing special and it's going to be fast enough for you to not even see the computation. Your approach to generate the dataframe is pretty straight forward since you are accessing the dicitonary by key. If you need to create dynamic dataframes, you can use pandas and create dataframes from those dictionaries with pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary_object).

Thanks. Is there a good practice regarding using these models in an API? Should I store it in memory or read it everytime someone sends in a request? Also regarding the schema changes, there is no way for Pydantic to handle schema changes right?

To use models in an api... I guess you are talking about a web service. You can stream the output if you need, or if you see it's too heavy you can create pickle files that work as a trained model with an input and an output, and can be stored and accessed by your api service. About that pydantic question... python is a dynamic language, you need to raise your own tracebacks if you want to determine the functinal schema. Pydantic can help you with those raises. Check the raise function (i dont use pydantic, so keep studying it just in case)

Thanks for your answer Jose, I might not have explained it well, I was referring to pydantic models. I'm using FastAPI framework to create an API, the data is read using pandas to dictionaries. Should I parse the dictionaries and create Pydantic models for each row every single time someone tries to access an endpoint, or is there a more efficient approach (caching it somewhere)? Also, how can I handle potential CSV schema changes without manually updating Pydantic models?
